# Convert all tables in a MySQL database to utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, type-conversion, collation

I want to convert all tables in a MySQL database to `utf8_general_ci`.  I have tried `ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` but it only changes new tables, not existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in [this blog post](https://georgepavlides.info/convert-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-to-utf8_general_ci), it is possible to use a mysql `select` to create a query to update the character set and collation of all tables in a database.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', t.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', t.TABLE_NAME, ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ')
FROM information_schema.TABLES t 
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = '[ADD-YOUR-DB-NAME-HERE]'
```

Then run the resulting queries to actually convert your tables.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to phpmyadmin and click on Operations and change 'Collation' select drop-down list. Select `utf8_general_ci` and all tables will be changed.

[image]

Comment: This does not change all tables

Comment: If this is when just a database is selected, this only changes the default for new tables that are created but does not change any existing table collation. But if you first select a table and then go to operations and change collation it will alter the collation.